# Yocto project rabbitmq-server recipe build

Tags: rabbitmq, yocto, bitbake

I want to add rabbitmq-server recipe to my yocto project. As mentioned on http://layers.openembedded.org/ the rabbitmq-server is a part of meta-cloud-service/meta-opestack layer. I have cloned the layer in my project and added the required paths to bblayers.conf.
Now, when I try to build the rabbitmq-server recipe by bitbake rabbitmq-server command, I get following response as error:

> WARNING: base-files-3.0.14-r89 do_fetch: Failed to fetch URL
>   file://nsswitch.conffile://print_issue.sh, attempting MIRRORS if
>   available ERROR: base-files-3.0.14-r89 do_fetch: Fetcher failure:
>   Unable to find file file://nsswitch.conffile://print_issue.sh
>   anywhere.
>
> ERROR: base-files-3.0.14-r89 do_fetch: Fetcher failure for URL:
>   'file://nsswitch.conffile://print_issue.sh'. Unable to fetch URL from
>   any source. ERROR: base-files-3.0.14-r89 do_fetch: Function failed:
>   base_do_fetch

Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I use RabbitMQ but didn't manage to install it within meta-openstack.
I did install all needed components with [meta-erlang](https://github.com/meta-erlang/meta-erlang)
Note you should adjust version of erlang and elixir with somethink like follow code in your build/local.conf

```
PREFERRED_VERSION_erlang = "22%" #instead of latest v.23
PREFERRED_VERSION_erlang-native = "22%"

PREFERRED_VERSION_elixir = "1.10.0"
PREFERRED_VERSION_elixir-native = "1.10.0"
```

That way I've manage to install and use RabbitMQ-server v3.8.21-r1 even at Yocto 2.6 Thud which is fairly outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple layers are modifying the base-files recipe and together they are making a mess of it.

The [meta-openstack SRC_URI modifications](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-cloud-services/tree/meta-openstack/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_openstack.inc) use this

```
SRC_URI += "file://nsswitch.conf"
```

This will ensure that a space is added before the added string, but does not leave an empty space after the string (like e.g. the original base-files recipe does).

After this another layer probably does

```
SRC_URI_append = "file://print_issue.sh \
                 "
```

or something like it, assuming there's a space in the end of SRC_URI, and the URLs get mushed together. One or both of the recipe modifications should be fixed so this does not happen.

Comment: Hi Jussi, 
Thanks for that. The base_file error has gone but now it gives some oe_runmake error for rabbitmq recipe. The error is as follow:

Comment: Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4
| Makefile:379: deps.mk: No such file or directory
| python codegen.py body codegen/amqp-rabbitmq-0.9.1.json codegen/credit_extension.json src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1.erl
| python codegen.py body codegen/amqp-rabbitmq-0.8.json src/rabbit_framing_amqp_0_8.erl
| xsltproc --novalid --stringparam modulename "`basename src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl .erl`" \
|  docs/usage.xsl docs/rabbitmqctl.1.xml > src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl.tmp

Comment: | xsltproc --novalid --stringparam modulename "`basename src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl .erl`" \
|  docs/usage.xsl docs/rabbitmq-plugins.1.xml > src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl.tmp
| sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/%QUOTE%/"/g' src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl.tmp > src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl.tmp2
| sed -e 's/"/\\"/g' -e 's/%QUOTE%/"/g' src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl.tmp > src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl.tmp2
| fold -s src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl.tmp2 > src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl.tmp3
| fold -s src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl.tmp2 > src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl.tmp3

Comment: /bin/sh: 1: fold: not found
| /bin/sh: 1: fold: not found
| Makefile:306: recipe for target 'src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl' failed
| make: *** [src/rabbit_plugins_usage.erl] Error 127
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| Makefile:306: recipe for target 'src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl' failed
| make: *** [src/rabbit_ctl_usage.erl] Error 127
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.

Comment: That's a completely unrelated error. Quick look at the meta-openstack rabbitmq-server recipe implies that the issue has been fixed 2.5 years ago...